Failed to execute greengrass cli command from Nodejs app (edge ubuntu machine)
I have Greengrass edge machine (which is Ubuntu machine basically).
I open its terminal and run sudo /greengrass/v2/bin/greengrass-cli component list
and it return me desire result.

I have Nodejs app and from Nodejs app, I want to execute the same command. The node code looks as below,
greengrass.controller.js
const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;

const listcmd = execSync("sudo /greengrass/v2/bin/greengrass-cli component list", {
      stdio: "inherit",
      shell: "/bin/bash"
});


After writing above code, I create docker image and container of node app.
I run AWS greengrass IOT core pipeline and deploy this container to edge machine (to same ubuntu machine)
I execute my deployed node app on the edge machine and it throws error that failed to execute command but while executing the same command in the terminal, works fine.

Que: What is wrong with it? What should be the root cause of it ?

What is the actual error?  What class of "component" is this supposed to list?  It's possible this won't work in a container, either because the container has its own isolated filesystem and can't see the host system's software components, or because the container can't access hardware devices.  Running sudo from inside another program can also be tricky (how would you give it a password?) and you may need to run the server directly as root.
